# What is conversational convention for naming the Ten Commandments?

Tags: discussion

To avoid confusion, is it best to say "Commandment-against-killing"?

Or is the numbering confusion only affecting Lutherans? (Have Catholics and all of evangelicalism the same system)?

Answer (score 1):

The numbering system is not consistent across traditions. Referring to commandments only by number is likely to be confusing, although in context it is rare that one cannot figure out which commandment is being referred to.

Using the one you picked, depending on your numbering system and critical text it could be the 5th, 6th or 7th commandment. However in context it is unlikely no matter which number you stick that the wrong commandment could be assumed. For example in the following, no matter which number you fill in, the commandment in question is obviously the one about murder.

> The {5,6,7}th commandment tells us something about the value of life; as we were made by another and belong not to ourselves but to the one who made us, so we must not wantonly take away what we cannot give.

From a pragmatic standpoint, it is probably better to spell it out to avoid any possible ambiguity or making your audience look it up and count.

However as long as you are going to spell it out, I would highly recommend doing so with the language of the day rather than several hundred year old English. The King James translation is highly identifiable and Christians own a huge debt to the fantastic work, but using it's wording outside of the context of a direct quote introduces a misunderstanding in this case. In every day modern English "kill" means something different than it does in the KJV translation of that verse. Those who understand how English has changed over time might catch the difference, but many people do not. Whenever referring to the commandment in your own words you should help people avoid this confusion by using the word "murder" which has the same meaning in modern English as "kill" did a couple hundred years ago (which it quite distinct from the modern meaning of "kill").

Pragmatically, "the commandment against murder" should clue people in to your topic pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As for your editorial about kill/murder, my thesis is that when the various catechism writers explained the faith, they explicitly defined the obligations under kill/murder Commandment to include ways that are objected to by recent political movements who prefer limiting it to "kill".

Comment: @pterandon Your thesis is grounded in neither history nor linguistics. Catechism writers have nothing to do with this. You can easily find a history of translations over the past few thousand years and verify that nobody has "changed" anything. The meaning of "kill" in English has changed over time and translations have adapted to stay true to the meaning of the Hebrew. Any decent hermeneutical treatment of the text will point you to the Hebrew context of "unlawful taking of life" which is in contrast to other parts of the Mosaic law that included provisions lawful killing.

Comment: Linguistically, you're spot-on. Perhaps I shouldn't have presumed your beliefs here. But I have seen a guy who objected to the "touchy-feely" liberal ethic of promoting your neighbor's physical well-being, found in most of the catechisms; he liked that it was limited to a restriction on unlawful killing. I was referring to the active duty to help, even enemies, which sort of makes the distinctions about kinds of killing less of an opportunity to put your feet up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where scoping the question helps.  If you ask a question about the 4th commandment and want Catholic answers, the answers are going to be about honoring your parents!

This question [I asked a while ago](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/protestant-numbering-of-the-10-commandments) needs a better answer, if you can help.

If you're confused as to the numbering schemes, [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-are-there-different-divisions-of-the-ten-commandments) has good answers.

The Catechism of the Catholic Church makes it clear that the Catholic numbering system of the commandments is concise and universal to the whole Church, so

Comment: In this context, I was answering a question as to whether something were in the bible, and referring to the Ten Commandments seemed like the best answer. If denominational posturing were unneeded anywhere, it is in such a question.   The conflation of Roman Catholic particulars and "universal to the whole Church" is a bit arrogant.

Comment: I was going to use the word sect, but it didn't seem big enough. Mean, universal to the Catholic Church, which in the end will be redundant, but for the time being reeks of arrogance.